# UITapGestureRecognizer to add on screen of type UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to add UITapGestureRecognizer on a class of type UIView on the object UITableView and one gesture on UILabel with attributed text for clickable link. But strange part is that gesture works only when i add it to self not on _tableView. Please guide is it possible to add gestures on UIView class objects.

Below is the code what i tried.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = 
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapp)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    gestureRecognizer.view.tag = 1;
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is self in addGestureRecognizer?  Nobody knows for sure what it is.

Comment: self means it is adding on current class which is of type UIView not UIViewController.

Comment: What i want to achieve is to add it on tableView rather than self because if i add on tableview it doesn't work.

Comment: [addGestureRecognizer:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622496-addgesturerecognizer?language=objc) is a method on UIView so you should be able to add them to your table view (which inherits from UIScrollView and UIView) or content in your UITableViewCell objects or the container view of your UITableView.  However your taps on the table view may not be getting recognized if you are tapping on cells or content that is ignoring the touch and not processing user interaction (e.g. labels) or if didSelectRowAtIndexPath is firing.